# Unable to update null value in UUID column postrgres via jpa native query

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to update with null value in uuid column in postgres db using jpa

Here is my code:

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update student set teacher_id=:teacherId where studentId=:studentId", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateTeacherUUID(@Param("teacherId") UUID teacherId, @Param("studentId") UUID studentId);

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

   @Id
   UUID studentId;
   
   @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
   @Column(name = "teacher_id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
   UUID teacherId;
}
```

I am getting below error when I try to update

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42804
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "teacher_id" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Note: This issue occurring only in jpa native queries If I update directly using repository.update or hql its working fine

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: What version of Postgres dialect is configured for your dataSource? You probably should configure dialect to be 8.2+ version (where UUID support was introduced) or create custom UUID type converter, because by default UUID is being converted to `byte[]` which is not what you want

Comment: I am using postgres version 42.4.1. I am facing issue only with jpa native queries. If I directly update entity(repository.save) or hql its working fine. I can update non null value only the issue with updating null